# Pythagoras triangle

Tags: c#, math

I would like to ask you about this programing part, is it everything ok?
the task was:
Write the pseudocode or flow diagram and code for the theorem of Pythagoras - for right-angle triangle with three ribs (a, b, and c) of type integer

```
int KendiA = 0;
int KendiB = 0;
int H = 0;
string Trekendeshi = null;
int gjetja = 0;

for (KendiA = 1; KendiA <= 15; KendiA++)
{
    for (KendiB = 1; KendiB <= 15; KendiB++)
    {
        for (H = 1; H <= 30; H++)
        {
            if ((Math.Pow(KendiA, 2) + Math.Pow(KendiB, 2) == Math.Pow(H, 2)))
            {
                gjetja = gjetja + 1;
                Trekendeshi = gjetja + "\t" + KendiA + "\t" + KendiB + "\t" + H;
                Console.WriteLine(Trekendeshi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch. Please take some time to explain what you are trying to do here. Trying to explain should help you understand why this is wrong on all levels.

Comment: Does setting gjetja = 0 at completion of Internal For Loop, solve your problem ?

Comment: @Muggen Question says psuedo code, but this doesn't look like pseudo-code either. It looks like Java.

Comment: @Muggen: Obviously not. But that's the lesser problem.

Comment: Well, it should work. It could be improved in several ways. And it's not C, as tagged, but Java?

Comment: @Paul, I think it is C#. (I don't know C# at all. just seen some at random sites on the internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well but it prints repeated ones. Count **KendiB** from **KendiA**  solves your problem

```
for (KendiA = 1; KendiA <= 15; KendiA++){
       for (KendiB = KendiA; KendiB <= 15; KendiB++){
```

Here is simplest way

```
for(int i=2; i<10; i++){
   int a = 2*i;
   int b = i*i-1;
   int c = i*i+1;
   System.out.println(a + "  " + b + "  "  + c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have a right but in this line  "for (H = 1; H <= 30; H++)", hypotenuse cannot be greater than 30..?

Comment: it is just example. You can change 10 to your needs

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to find pythagorean triples than to iterate through every set of three.   Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples for instance.

Also, it's better to square integers by multiplying it with itself rather than using pow(i,2).